# GET call using restangular

Tags: angularjs, rest, get, restangular

I'm trying to use the GET method using Restangular to get some objects back from the backend using a rest call.

its a simple GET call..not sure why im getting an error. if someone can point out something im missing that would be great.

my restangular call:

```
        var vm = this;
        vm.getEvent = function() {
            Restangular.one('/services/v1').one('people').get();
        }
```

object i should be getting back looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "string",
    "description": "string",
    "locations": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "string",
        "description": "string"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "string",
    "description": "string",
    "locations": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "string",
        "description": "string"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "string",
    "description": "string",
    "locations": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "string",
        "description": "string"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Getting this error when i call it in html:

Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []

EDIT:

endpoint

http://localhost:3000/services/v1/people

Answer (score 0):

your code should be as below

```
var vm = this;
    vm.getEvent = function() {
        Restangular.one('/services/v1').get('people').then(function(data){console.log("data",data)});
    }
```